# Efficient-er(or more pythonic) iteration over list of Entities

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of entities (A class holding nothing but an ID, and attributes that are components added mixed in later.) in a list called pool, which has every single entity created by a factory.

this factory also has a method that will yield every entity with certain components:

```
def list(self, Search_ID = []):
    """
    Return a filtered list of the entities with certain components. If components
    are not given to the method, simply return all entities.
    """
    for entity in self.pool:
        if entity.has(Search_ID) is True:
            yield entity
```

This code becomes very much a speed bump when searching more than one component. This is used like `x.list(["position", "name"])` to yield every component from the list of pool that has both position and name.

The has method looks like:

```
def has(self, c_list = []):
    """
    Returns true if this entity has all the listed components within
    c_list.
    """
    for component in c_list:
        if not hasattr(self, component):
            return False

    return True
```

Im wondering if there is a more pythonic and efficient way of going over all this information, rather than just iterating over a list.

Comment: You could maintain a dictionary of sets, with the keys being the components and the sets being all entities with that component. Then for a multiple component search you can just union the relevant sets.

Comment: `c_list = []` as a default arg is usually a bad idea

Comment: for the method *has*, return all(hasattr(self, component) for component in c_list)

Comment: @GuilhermeSoares Implementing this dramatically slowed the entire system down. By about 105%

Comment: What about `return any(not hasattr(self, component) for component in c_list)`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yep, same effect. This isn't a question that needs an answer, but I'm glad someone tried, thank you. Without major restructuring I don't see there being a quick fix speed increase.

Comment: If the code works as-is, it should be posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thank you.

Comment: I think @TomDalton has the right idea, although it would be the intersection of the relevant sets and not the union.  Furthermore, depending on how often the list is updated, caching may be useful.